# Alerting a user that pop-up blockers are suppressing a canvas

Tags: html, canvas, popup

Browsers with pop-up blockers are suppressing a canvas element, and I would like to alert the user to this fact through a short text phrase stored beneath the canvas element. I would greatly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction, regarding a better method to alert the user to temporarily disable popups, or to better manage canvas to eliminate the blocking.

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bannerRotation.js"></script>
  <style>
     h1 {
     position:absolute;
     z-index:0;
     top: 200px;
     text-align: center;     
     }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       <div>
           <canvas id="showCanvas" width="800" height="400">Canvas not supported</canvas>
       </div>
       <h1>Please disable pop-up blockers for this site</h1> 
   </div>           
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by pop-up? Are you creating a pop-up window with the canvas in? Or are they going to a direct page and the canvas isn't displaying? Not all browsers can use the canvas tag, look at this sheet for reference http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, in this case the user is going to a direct page and the canvas is not displaying due to a popup blocker. Once the popup blocker is disabled, the canvas loads. I was aware that not all browsers can use the canvas tag, and wonder if I should be looking into a flash option?

Comment: If you can complete your task using Flash then go for it, but remember HTML5 and Flash both offer different features and problems :)

Comment: I haven't experienced this at all, have you got any sample code you can share with us to show how you are creating the pop-up and showing the canvas tag?

Comment: have you tried to removed the A tag around the CANVAS tag? that maybe causing a problem, see if that is the problem and if it is then we can think of a solution

Comment: @Canvas thanks so much for your idea, it turns out the following was successful for both AdBlock 2.7.13 in Chrome and AdBlock Plus 2.6.4 in Firefox: renaming the "bannerrotation.js" to a different name cleared the issue, as the adblockers have  "bannerrotation" as a filter.

Answer (score 1):

The following was successful for both AdBlock 2.7.13 in Chrome and AdBlock Plus 2.6.4 in Firefox: renaming the "bannerrotation.js" to a different name cleared the issue with the AdBlockers, as they have a "bannerrotation" keyword as a filter.

Comment: Nice one mate, make sure to tick this answer as the correct one